# Access method or property from parent within a non named slot in vuejs component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using Vue 2.4.1

And I'm trying to reproduce what is shown there : [link to alligator.io](https://alligator.io/vuejs/scoped-component-slots/)

Which is basycally accessing a non-named slot data.

```
//Chid Component
<template>
    <slot :test="myTest"></slot>
</template>

data(){
    return {
       myTest: "I should be getable"
    }
}

//Parent
<template>
    <child-component>
        <template scope="defaultSlotScope">
            {{defaultSlotScope.test}}
        </template>
    </child-component>
</template>
```

So this is the first time I see the mension of `scope="defaultSlotScope"` Is this the right way? However I don't find how to properly make this work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the *slot* in your child component which is missing in the parent;

```
<template>
  <child-component>
    <template scope="defaultSlotScope">
       {{defaultSlotScope.test}}
    </template>
  </child-component>
</template>
```

Also in the child component, you should not expose `slot` directly in the template root. Wrap it in another tag; The reason behind this is that the root template can accept only one element while a slot can be multiple:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <slot :test="myTest"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Ho yeah It was just a fail of me but ofc it is inside the child component

Comment: Did you *import* and *register* the child component in the parent?

Comment: totaly yes, everything else on this component is working

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem here, but I don't think you should use slot in the template root of the child component. `<template>
    <div><slot :test="myTest"></slot></div>
</template>`